# Continue function after error / try - catch

Tags: java, try-catch

I have a function in a server that sometimes throws an error and seems to crash the server.

Do `try-catch` blocks prevent servers/program from completly crashing and continue to process? This code handles network requests and I need to make sure the server does not crash and prevent the processing of other network requests to the same function because of an error that occurred and crashed the server.

A common error is a `java null pointer exception`

EDIT added example pseudo code:

```
public class myClass{
    public static string networkHandler(string s) { //static method
         try {
           string ss = s;
         }
         catch(string s) {
           //handle error
         }
    }
}
```

I am wondering if it is because I need to write another catch block to handle the specific type of error that is crashing the server.

Edit: As answered by @denis, I was wondering if there was a wy to have a catch block of type NullPointerException

Comment: what did you come up with? attach your code to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A try catch allows you to catch an error (that will stop your program from completely crashing) and you can then handle the error. However something like a NullPointerException typically indicates an error in your code.

There's some more info on exception handling here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html

Comment: Can there be an exception for a NullPointerException so that it doesnt crash the server?

Comment: A NullPointerException is a RuntimeException so it will bubble up out of your code if not explicitly caught.  Additionally, as has been mentioned in previous comments, this is a gap in your code that needs to be fixed.  If you have a line where it is okay for a NPE to occur and just continue then wrap that specific section in a try/catch targetting the NPE.  However, a global catch and just allowing things to continue will more than likely result in more issues than it fixes.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your server environment and frameworks you should have a global exception handling strategy. Local try-catches can only prevent crashes to that specific exceptions on that specific location.

Furthermore, null pointed exceptions are signs of code and algorithms issues so better seek the root cause and fix it

Comment: Yes I agree, but the code I work with is legacy and very hard to find the source. I think the business needs are to just prevent the server from crashing regardless of error. So I am wondering if here is a way to prevent Null Pointer Exceptions from crashing the server? Is there a way to make a catch block that handles Null Pointer exception types?

Comment: Yes .. see denis answer it seems good to me .. but still the rule should be never allow random null pointer exceptions :)

Answer (score 1):

If the NullPointerException is your culprit then catch an exception like this

```
    try {
       // code that throws null pointer excpetion that crashes the server
    }
    catch(NullPointerExcpetion npe) {
       //handle error
    }
```

It should prevent server from crashing from this specific exception.

Comment: nice, I will try this

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to use `try-catch` and you are using it wrong in your pseudocode.

```
try {
    string ss = s;
}catch(string s) {
     //handle error
}
```

you are passing an string to catch which is wrong. you should pass an exception that you want to be catched. in this case `NullPointerException`, so you can rewrite it like :

```
try {
    string ss = s;
}catch(NullPointerException ex) {
     //handle error
}
```

you can read [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flow-control-in-try-catch-finally-in-java/) for more information about try-catch-finally structure in java.

Comment: yes, my fault, I should have been more clear but the pseudo code is a example of what is already there. I plan to add another catch block specifically for the NPE

Comment: you can use an exception without any type, but i don't recommend it, it'll catch whatever exception happens.

Comment: btw check out this link for more built-in java exceptions : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/types-of-exception-in-java-with-examples/